# IdentityServer4 EF Core

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I wanted to move my api/client configs to sql instead of being in memory.  I followed the tutorial and I haven't been able to get it to generate the EF Migrations or DBContext via AddConfigurationStore and AddOperationalStore.  I keep getting an error saying "no project.json is found" or if I run the add-migration in package manager "Build Failed".  I'm assuming that the docs haven't been updated since VS migrated away from project.json to csproj.

Is there anything in particular I can do to generate these dbcontexts and migration scripts without doing it manually (I can do it manually using the samples that you have, but I worry that if it's ever updated in the future then, I'll end up with a gap somewhere that will be hard to troubleshoot)?

The tutorial I'm referring to: [Tutorial](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html)
The sample code tied to the tutorial is here: [Sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/8_EntityFrameworkStorage)

Comment: You might want to provide a link to the tutorial and samples to which you are referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer is currently only supporting the 1.0.0-preview2-003131 SDK. Meaning only VS2015 Update 3 and project.json until csproj is finalized/VS2017 is released.

> IdentityServer is built against ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 using the 1.0.0-preview2-003131 SDK. This is the only configuration we are going to support on the issue tracker.
>
> Also we are staying on the project.json based tooling until Visual Studio 2017 has been released - IOW you need to use Visual Studio Update 3 with the preview ASP.NET Core tooling.
>
> -- https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4#platform